# Однотипные потоки

Tags: потоки-данных, многопоточность, java, сокет

Какое то время назад я написал парсер, который бегает на сайты за информацией, за один цикл он может сделать от 1 до 4-5 запросов на сайты. И вот мне захотелось добавить многопоточности так как объемы данных сильно увеличились. Переделал все под `runable` интерфейс с использованием `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`(на 6 потоков, 3 ядерный проц), фактически в каждом потоке запускается экземпляр парсера, но работать быстрее не стало, а может стало даже медленнее.

Может ли это происходить изза того что потоки пытаются одновременно делать запросы, то есть они все пытаются заюзать 80 порт, становятся там в очередь и изза это прироста фактически нет?

Может ли влиять то что сервер находится на виртуальном хостинге и изза этого работа нативных тридов как то нарушается?

Comment: Так проанализируйте работу ваших потоков. Может быть они все блокируются на общем ресурсе и из-за этого выполняются последовательно. А может вы неправильно сконфигурировали ваш Executor. И еще много чего может, только зачем гадать. Логи и thread dump вам в помощь.

Comment: @sonniy, потоки делают запросы на все один сайт или по разным сайтам (IP) ?

И конфигурация хостинга, конечно, может иметь значение. Если реально у Вас там виртуалка с одним (и тоже виртуальным процессором), то чем больше потоков, тем медленнее все вместе будет крутиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь нужно выяснить, чем заняты ваши потоки. Блокируются они или ждут ответа от сервера? А может уже качают, но скорости не хватает?
Для этого вам нужно использовать или
1) jvisualvm, входящий в состав jdk, с помощью него подключится к процессу и просмотреть, в каком состоянии потоки.
2_ И также можно сделать дамп потоков или с помощью команды jstack или с помощью того же  jvisualvm, и тогда вы получите stacktrace ваших потоков и можете увидеть, что они делают в текущий момент.

При установке плагина "Threads Inspector" в jvisualvm вы можете делать дамп потоков прямо из jvisualvm

Comment: jmx + jvisualvm творят чудеса :D